# ListView ClientSize to big

Tags: c#, .net, listview

We have a couple of listviews where i set the column widths by percent

```
columnWidth = (double)CustomerListView.ClientSize.Width * double.Parse("0,15");
CustomerListView.Columns[0].Width = (int)columnWidth;

columnWidth = (double)CustomerListView.ClientSize.Width * double.Parse("0,05");
CustomerListView.Columns[1].Width = (int)columnWidth;
```

etc

The listview size is never changed

```
this.CustomerListView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(970, 341);
```

This works just fine. Except on this one computer...
The clisentsize returns column widths in excess of 10000!
Have only found this issue on one customer computer so far.

So my question is:
What can affect the ClientSize of the listview?

The resolution on the computer is 1680x1050.

Comment: This of course won't work correctly on a machine whose language doesn't use a comma for a decimal point.  You'll multiply by 15 instead of 0.15.  Do not use strings to represent floating point values.  Or parse them with a specific CultureInfo.NumberFormat, InvariantCulture was made for that.

Comment: This of course is the correct answer. Damn legacy code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer taken from the commend Hans Passant made.**

"This of course won't work correctly on a machine whose language doesn't use a comma for a decimal point. You'll multiply by 15 instead of 0.15. Do not use strings to represent floating point values. Or parse them with a specific CultureInfo.NumberFormat, InvariantCulture was made for that." –  Hans Passant Aug 28 at 13:43